# Aptana Studio 3.6.0 - Fuzzy File Finder

Tags: aptana, aptana3, fuzzy-search, file-search

Back in the early versions of Aptana 3 we had a plugin to add fuzzy finding capability to files search.
It was called **Muermann GoTo File**, and the shortcut was *CTRL+Alt+N*.

We could just drop the plugin inside Aptana's plugins folder, and the fuzzy search would be enabled:

Example:

```
Search Term: profcontsp

Results:
profiles_controller_spec.rb
...
```

Now, updating to Aptana 3.6.0, I tried adding that same plugin on the plugins folder without success.
Tried the dropins folder as well...no deal. Tried putting only the .jar inside those folders.. no good.

That would be amazing if there was a way to use the same plugin or even another one to add the same feature. I've got kind of addicted to it.

Any suggestions?